# How to change JSON format?

Tags: javascript

I want to change the below JSON Data to Expected Format.

**JSON DATA:**

```json
[
  {
    "A": {
      "X": "P"
    },
    "B": {
      "X": "Q"
    },
    "C": {
      "X": "R"
    }
  }
]
```

**Expected Format:**

```json
[
  {  
    "A": "P",
    "B": "Q",
    "C": "R"
  }      
]
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: What did you try? Where are you struggling? Please have a look at the FAQ and try to edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Where is the code you tried ?

Comment: @C-Otto and Weedoze , I am new to this that is why forgot to post my code....i already got my answer from Suren Srapyan ....... thanks for looking into my question.

Comment: @Weedoze sorry for incontinence..

Answer (score 2):

Try this. You can get the keys of the each item and then map to the correspond structure of object.

```js
const json = [
    {  
         "A":{  
            "X":"P"
         },
         "B":{  
            "X":"Q"
         },
         "C":{  
            "X":"R"
         }
    }  
];

const expectedJSON = json.map(item => {
  const obj = {};
  Object.keys(item).forEach(key => obj[key] = item[key].X);
  return obj;
})

console.log(expectedJSON);
```

Answer (score 1):

In case `X` property has different names for each object you can use this method.

```js
const json = {
  "A": { "X": "P" },
  "B": { "X": "Q" },
  "C": { "X": "R" }
};

for (let prop in json) {
  for (let item in json[prop]) {
    json[prop] = json[prop][item];
  }
}

console.log(json);
```